# Object has no attribute error while using ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm a python newbie and have the following problem. If I uncomment the last line of this code:

```
# traverse all directories
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args.rootfolder):
    for file in files:
        print('Current file name: ' + file)
        if file.endswith('.savx'):
            # read single xml savx file
            currfilename = os.path.join(root,file)
            print('Current full file name: ' + currfilename)
            tree = ET.parse(currfilename)
            # root = tree.getroot() <-- if I uncomment this line I get errors
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 30, in <module>
    currfilename = os.path.join(root,file)
  File "C:\progs\develop\Python34\lib\ntpath.py", line 108, in join
    result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
  File "C:\progs\develop\Python34\lib\ntpath.py", line 161, in splitdrive
    normp = p.replace(_get_altsep(p), sep)
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

It looks like the error appears after the second `file in files` loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `root` twice in your code, for different things:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args.rootfolder):
#   ^^^^
```

and

```
root = tree.getroot()
```

So when you try to use `root` as a path string when building the next filename to load:

```
currfilename = os.path.join(root,file)
```

you'll find you replaced the `root` path name with an ElementTree object instead.

Use a different name for either the root directory name or your ElementTree object. Use `dirname` for example:

```
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(args.rootfolder):
    for file in files:
        print('Current file name: ' + file)
        if file.endswith('.savx'):
            # read single xml savx file
            currfilename = os.path.join(dirname, file)
            print('Current full file name: ' + currfilename)
            tree = ET.parse(currfilename)
            root = tree.getroot()
```